Can't find correct reaction loads for statically indeterminate problem
been working on this problem all day and I feel as if I am going crazy. I am using SkyCiv to confirm the right answer and cannot get close to it, I have messed up both my attempts at superimposing and just integrating. I cannot tell if it is necessary to split the problem into two regions. I must be on my 5th way of approaching it, any help is appreciated.
The problem shows a 15 ft long beam, cantilevered on the left and a pin support on the right. The beam is under an external force of (-30 * 10^3)X/15 + 10 * 10^3 (I calculated this, In the diagram the leftmost side is subjected with a 10 * 10^3 lb/ft up, which decreases to a -20 * 10^3 lb/ft load at 15 m). What are the reactions at the wall at pin?
When plugged into SkyCiv, it feeds out a wall reaction of 112501.7 (CCW) lbft, and 7500 lb (up). The pin experiences 67500 lb (up).

Stop using software and draw it out.  Then we can help you.
